# Program to check if an number contained in another number

Tags: c

i did a program that can check if a number contained in another number , for example :
1234
234
does 1234 contain 234 ? yes . print true 
1234
943
does 1234 contain 943 ? no . print false
my problem that i don't know how should i print false , i have an problematic if , so how i can print false only if the number not contained ? if the program prints true its also print false anyway , so how i can make it print false only if the number not contained ?
my code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int firstnumb, tobechecked, numberofdigits = 0, hezka;
    scanf("%d %d", &firstnumb, &tobechecked);
    numberofdigits = log10(tobechecked) + 1;
    hezka = pow(10, numberofdigits);
    while (firstnumb > 0) {
        if (firstnumb % hezka == tobechecked) {
            printf("true");
        }
        firstnumb = (firstnumb / 10);
    }
    printf("false");

}
```

edited :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int firstnumb, tobechecked, numberofdigits = 0, hezka , result = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &firstnumb, &tobechecked);
    numberofdigits = log10(tobechecked) + 1;
    hezka = pow(10, numberofdigits);
    while (firstnumb > 0) {
        if (firstnumb % hezka == tobechecked) {
            result = 1;
        }
        firstnumb = (firstnumb / 10);
    }
    if (result) {
        printf("true");
    }
    else {

        printf("false");
    }

}
```

Comment: `123123` and `123` will print twice `true`. Is that the expected behaviour ?

Comment: @Cid you sure ? i checked again and it gives me one time true

Comment: Ah, maybe not, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of time the number to be checked was found. Then, after the while loop, use that count to determine if you print true or false.

```
int count = 0;

while (firstnumb > 0) {
    if (firstnumb % hezka == tobechecked) {
        count++;
    }
    firstnumb = (firstnumb / 10);
}

if (count == 0)
{
    printf("false");
}
else
{
    printf("true");
}
```